# Q: Different version between Development and Deployment iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Quick question : 
When I build my apps the standard version of iOS is 10.0 for minimum requirement and iPhone 5.
If I tried to deploy it into 9.0 and iPhone 5 as the minimum standard, will it effect anything ? like lack of performance or maybe I can't use the apps? 
Or I have to write a specific code into my apps to run that things ? Can I have some information/link about this.

p.s : I use swift code.

Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The type of device (iPhone 5, 6, 6 Plus, whatever...) is not really important if you're using Storyboards with constraints (there are exceptions, of course, but in general there are no big differences between different devices if you use the correct constraints).

The minimum deployment target **is** important if you're running on older iOS versions. A new method can be available on iOS 10 (and the code will compile fine), but on iOS 8 (for example), it will crash because the method is not available.

I would recommend you always setting the lowest deployment target you want to target and develop for that.

Example? From the `Timer` class, the constructor `init(timeInterval:, repeats:, block:)` isn't available on iOS 9 or lower.

Comment: so basically if I already set the minimum standard is iOS 10, probably lower than that will be crash or some function will failed in the apps ? 
The constraints not that important because I build the apps using a code, so it will fits all iphone.

Comment: @StevenTan yes, exactly. It may even not run at all on versions lower than that. I would recommend you always set the minimum version possible (in my case, I always use iOS 8) and always test on a device running that version (or, if not possible, at least test on the simulator to ensure it doesn't crash). You should also integrate some service like Fabric (Crashlytics) which will tell you if something crashed.